# What could cache an unsaved Sketch (Mac Image Creation Software) file to be opened on a different computer when openning sketch?

Tags: macos, google-drive, sketchup

This weekend I started a new sketch project on my personal Macbook. I didn't spend long on it. I just put a couple images together and saved a new image. I didn't bother to save the sketch project after I finished, but just saved the image.

The following day at work on my work computer, early in the day, I feel like my computer has some kind of memory leak slowing it down (semi-normal for me) so I restart it. After the restart, I open sketch, and the unsaved sketch project I worked on in my personal laptop pops up as an unsaved sketch project on this computer. The same one I had only ever worked on in my personal laptop at my house and never touched here. Luckily, my boss is an easy person to appease, because he was looking at the project when it opened and I explained I was not spending my time at work doing other things.

This made me flip out. I am a software developer and know that nothing happens like that without the computer being told to do so. So what saved the unsaved project and opened it on my work computer.

I use the same google accounts being saved on both computers. The sketch applications are not owned by the same person. My personal computer is mine and at work my boss set it up. My work computer is not associated with my apple ID. My laptop has never had access to the network my work computer runs on. My laptop was in my backpack though, several feet away from my work computer, though I had not even opened it up during this day.

Nothing really makes sense about this, and I understand that being irreproducible, I can't expect anyone to dig into this. If anyone has an inkling of how this happened to me though, I am drastically curious!!!!!

Just saying, I put sketchup as a tag, but this happened in regular sketch Version 40.3.

Comment: Same Google account, same data across all machines signed into that account. It's like Apple's handoff. Quick fix, don't use your home ID at work.

Comment: That is insane that Google has that kind of access to my offline computer programs while logged in. I appreciate the effort, but is there any way to turn this off? Is I lose something locally, it is my own fault and I deserve to lose it. I don't want google to have that level of access to my computer.